# Emscripten await operator in C++. Returns undefined instead of string value

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten, brave

I have this function "**IsBrave**" in my main.cpp.
If browser contains `navigator.brave` it calls the `navigator.brave.isBrave()` function with await.

But when call from browser's console the exported function, it prints **undefined** value instead of **"Brave"** on Brave browser. In other browsers result is **"Unknown"**.

**Tested in Brave Browser's Console**

```
> var x = await navigator.brave.isBrave(); console.log(x);
true

>var y = Main.Module.IsBrave(); console.log(y);
undefined
It's Brave.
```

**Desired output**

```
> var x = await navigator.brave.isBrave(); console.log(x);
true

>var y = Main.Module.IsBrave(); console.log(y);
It's Brave.
true
```

I've printed something before the return val(u8"Brave"), no problem. But in browser's console get **undefined** value.

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

```
int main()
{
}

emscripten::val IsBrave()
{
    using namespace emscripten;
    bool isBrave = !!val::global()[u8"navigator"][u8"brave"] && !!(val::global()[u8"navigator"][u8"brave"].call<val>(u8"isBrave").await());
    if(isBrave)
    {
        std::cout<< "It's Brave." << std::endl; // PRINTED OK
        return val(u8"Brave"); // GET undefined in BROWSER
    }
    else
    {
        return val(u8"Unknown");
    }
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(exports)
{
    using namespace emscripten;
    function<val>(u8"IsBrave", &IsBrave);
}
```

Compiled with

```
em++.bat `
main.cpp `
-I ../CppInclude `
-I Include `
-o Module.js `
-std=c++17 `
--bind `
-s WASM=1 `
-s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 `
-s SINGLE_FILE=0 `
-s ASYNCIFY=1 `
-s VERBOSE=0 `
-O2 `
--profiling `
-s EXPORT_NAME=`'CreateModuleInstance`' `
-s MODULARIZE=1 `
-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=[`'_main`'] `
-s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=[`'ccall`',`'cwrap`',`'lengthBytesUTF8`',`'stringToUTF8`'] `
--pre-js "Js/Pre_Compiled.js" `
--post-js "Js/Post_Compiled.js" `
--extern-post-js "Js/ExternPost_Compiled.js" `
--extern-pre-js "Js/ExternPre_Compiled.js" `
```

Comment: `javascript != c++` ???

Comment: what is undefined? post the full error log please! `Module` is not in global context so it can't be call directly from console. try putting `window.Module = Module` in `onRuntimeInitialized`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this example [EmbindAsync](https://github.com/Satancito/EmbindAsync)